# WordPress custom post pagination by category wise

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-gutenberg

I use a 'CPT(custom post type) ajax pagination' wordpress plugin to show pagination in my any pages. It works perfectly, shows all posts in where im put pagination shortcode on pages. I'm having some trouble, I'm created a pages to show posts in pages with category wise. 'CPT(custom post type) ajax pagination' plugin has an option but it's not working. `[cptapagination custom_post_type='yourposttype' cptataxname='taxonamyname' cptacatname='categoryname' post_limit='5']`.
I am trying to customize the code but its not working. 
Please help me to solve this problem. Please check below code

```
function cptapagination_callback() {
    global $wpdb, $post;
    $cptaNumber = absint($_POST['number']);
    $cptaLimit  = absint($_POST['limit']);
    $cptaType = sanitize_text_field($_POST['post']);
    $cptaCatName = sanitize_text_field($_POST['cptacatname']);
    $cptataxname = sanitize_text_field($_POST['category']);
    if( $cptaNumber == "1" ){
        $cptaOffsetValue = "0";
        if( $cptataxname ) {
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => $cptaLimit,'post_type' => $cptaType,$cptataxname=>$cptaCatName,'post_status' => 'publish');       
        }else{
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => $cptaLimit,'post_type' => $cptaType,'post_status' => 'publish');  
        }
    }else{
        $cptaOffsetValue = ($cptaNumber-1)*$cptaLimit;
        if( $cptataxname ) {
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => $cptaLimit,'post_type' => $cptaType,$cptataxname=>$cptaCatName,'offset' => $cptaOffsetValue,'post_status' => 'publish');
        }else{
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => $cptaLimit,'post_type' => $cptaType,'offset' => $cptaOffsetValue,'post_status' => 'publish'); 
        }

    }
    $cptaQuery = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $cptaQuery->have_posts() ){
            while( $cptaQuery->have_posts() ){ $cptaQuery->the_post();
                 echo "<div class='cpta-Section'>
                    <a href=".get_the_permalink()." class='btn-cptapagi'><h1>".get_the_title()."</h1></a>

                </div>";
            } wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        if($cptataxname!=""){
            $cpta_args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type' => $cptaType,$cptataxname=>$cptaCatName,'post_status' => 'publish');
        }else{
            $cpta_args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type' => $cptaType,'post_status' => 'publish');
        }
        $cpta_Query = new WP_Query( $cpta_args );
        $cpta_Count = count($cpta_Query->posts);
        $cpta_Paginationlist = ceil($cpta_Count/$cptaLimit);
        $last = ceil( $cpta_Paginationlist );
        if( $cptaNumber>1 ){ $cptaprev = $cptaNumber-1; }
        if( $cptaNumber < $last ){ $cptanext = $cptaNumber+1; }

        $adjacents = "2"; 
        $setPagination = "";
        if( $cpta_Paginationlist > 0 ){

            $setPagination .="<ul class='list-cptapagination'>";
            $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:cptaajaxPagination($cptaprev,$cptaLimit)'>Prev</a></li>";

            if ( $cpta_Paginationlist < 7 + ($adjacents * 2) ){

                for( $cpta=1; $cpta<=$cpta_Paginationlist; $cpta++){

                    if( $cptaNumber ==  $cpta ){ $active="active"; }else{ $active=""; }
                    $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination($cpta,$cptaLimit);'>$cpta</a></li>";

                }

            } else if ( $cpta_Paginationlist > 5 + ($adjacents * 2) ){

                if( $cptaNumber < 1 + ($adjacents * 2) ){

                    for( $cpta=1; $cpta <=4 + ($adjacents * 2); $cpta++){

                        if( $cptaNumber ==  $cpta ){ $active="active"; }else{ $active=""; }
                        $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination($cpta,$cptaLimit);'>$cpta</a></li>";
                    }
                    $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext dots'>...</li>";
                    $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:cptaajaxPagination($last,$cptaLimit)'>".$last."</a></li>";

                } elseif( $cpta_Paginationlist - ($adjacents * 2) > $cptaNumber && $cptaNumber > ($adjacents * 2)) { 

                    $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination(1,$cptaLimit);'>1</a></li>";
                    $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext dots'>...</li>";

                    for( $cpta=$cptaNumber - $adjacents; $cpta<=$cptaNumber + $adjacents; $cpta++){

                        if( $cptaNumber ==  $cpta ){ $active="active"; }else{ $active=""; }
                        $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination($cpta,$cptaLimit);'>$cpta</a></li>";

                    }

                    $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext dots'>...</li>";
                    $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:cptaajaxPagination($last,$cptaLimit)'>".$last."</a></li>";

                } else {

                    $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination(1,$cptaLimit);'>1</a></li>";
                    $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext dots'>...</li>";

                    for ($cpta = $last - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $cpta <= $last; $cpta++){

                        if( $cptaNumber ==  $cpta ){ $active="active"; }else{ $active=""; }
                        $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination($cpta,$cptaLimit);'>$cpta</a></li>";

                    }

                }

            } else {

                for( $cpta=1; $cpta<=$cpta_Paginationlist; $cpta++){
                    if( $cptaNumber ==  $cpta ){ $active="active"; }else{ $active=""; }
                    $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination($cpta,$cptaLimit);'>$cpta</a></li>";
                }

            }
            $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:cptaajaxPagination($cptanext,$cptaLimit)'>Next</a></li>";
            $setPagination .="</ul>";
        }
        echo $setPagination;
    wp_die();
}

function cptapagination_default($atts) {
    global $wpdb;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array('custom_post_type' => '','cptataxname'=>'','cptacatname'=>'','post_limit' => ''),$atts,'cptapagination');

    if($atts['custom_post_type'] !="" ){
        $cptaType = sanitize_text_field($atts['custom_post_type']); 
    }else{
        $cptaType ="post";  
    }

    if($atts['cptacatname'] !="" ){
        $cptaCatName = sanitize_text_field($atts['cptacatname']);   
    }else{
        $cptaCatName ="uncategorized";  
    }

    if( $atts['post_limit'] !="" ){
        $cptaLimit= absint($atts['post_limit']);    
    }else{
        $cptaLimit=5;
    }


    if($atts['cptataxname']!=""){
        $cptataxname =  sanitize_text_field($atts['cptataxname']);
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => $cptaLimit,'post_type' => $cptaType,$cptataxname=>$cptaCatName,'post_status' => 'publish');
    }else{
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => $cptaLimit,'post_type' => $cptaType,'post_status' => 'publish');  
    }   


    $cptaQuery = new WP_Query( $args );
    echo "<div id='cptapagination-content'>";
        if( $cptaQuery->have_posts() ){
            while( $cptaQuery->have_posts() ){ $cptaQuery->the_post();
                 echo "<div class='cpta-Section'>
                 <a href=".get_the_permalink()." class='btn-cptapagi'>
                    <h1>".get_the_title()."</h1>
                 </a>
                </div>";
            } wp_reset_postdata();
        }
        if($cptataxname!=""){
            $cpta_args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type' => $cptaType,$cptataxname=>$cptaCatName,'post_status' => 'publish');
        }else{
            $cpta_args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type' => $cptaType,'post_status' => 'publish');
        }
        $cpta_Query = new WP_Query( $cpta_args );
        $cpta_Count = count($cpta_Query->posts);
        $cpta_Paginationlist = ceil($cpta_Count/$cptaLimit);
        $last = ceil( $cpta_Paginationlist );

        $adjacents = "2"; 
        $setPagination = "";
        if( $cpta_Paginationlist > 0 ){

            $setPagination .="<ul class='list-cptapagination'>";
            $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:cptaajaxPagination(1,$cptaLimit)'>Prev</a></li>";

            if ( $cpta_Paginationlist < 7 + ($adjacents * 2) ){

                for( $cpta=1; $cpta<=$cpta_Paginationlist; $cpta++){

                    if( $cpta ==  0 || $cpta ==  1 ){ $active="active"; }else{ $active=""; }
                    $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination($cpta,$cptaLimit);'>$cpta</a></li>";

                }

            } else if ( $cpta_Paginationlist > 5 + ($adjacents * 2) ){

                for( $cpta=1; $cpta <= 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $cpta++){
                    if( $cpta ==  0 || $cpta ==  1 ){ $active="active"; }else{ $active=""; }
                    $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination($cpta,$cptaLimit);'>$cpta</a></li>";
                }
                $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext dots'>...</li>";
                $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:cptaajaxPagination($last,$cptaLimit)'>".$last."</a></li>";

            } else {

                for( $cpta=1; $cpta<=$cpta_Paginationlist; $cpta++){
                    if( $cpta ==  0 || $cpta ==  1 ){ $active="active"; }else{ $active=""; }
                    $setPagination .="<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='post' class='$active' data-posttype='$cptaType' data-taxname='$cptataxname' data-cattype='$cptaCatName' onclick='cptaajaxPagination($cpta,$cptaLimit);'>$cpta</a></li>";
                }

            }
            $setPagination .="<li class='pagitext'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:cptaajaxPagination(2,$cptaLimit)'>Next</a></li>";
            $setPagination .="</ul>";
        }
        echo $setPagination;

    echo "</div>";
}
add_shortcode( 'cptapagination', 'cptapagination_default' );
```

Comment: If you are asking about a plugin, you would probably want to link correspondin plugin's documentation in the question. So that may be users who are not even used the plugin can helo you. Otherwise the probability of question getting answered is reduced.

Comment: This plugin has no documentation. i have checked this before. Please check below link https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ajax-pagnaition/

Comment: What you are trying to Customize ?

Comment: [cptapagination custom_post_type='post' cptataxname='category' cptacatname='national' post_limit='5'] im use this shortcode and set it to certain page. Here national is a post category. Im set this to certain page but it shows all category post. I want to show only a category that set in shortcode.